# Is ultimate tensile strength is constant for a material?

Tags: mechanical-engineering, materials, structural-analysis, stresses, material-science

Is **ultimate tensile strength** is constant for a material? I have performed a tensile test of a **frame tube** and I made the **dumbbell** for tensile test.
The test specimen (A) has a **thickness 2mm** while test specimen (B) has a **thickness 1.4mm**. For specimen (A) T.S is found **57.33 kgf/mm2** while for specimen B, T.S is found to be **55.42 kgf/mm2**. These values looks the same. Dumbbell size was **same** for both specimen.

Second question related to this is during tensile testing, I get **592.32 MPa** ultimate tensile strength, while mild steel tensile strength range is **(400~`550 MPa)** according to Google. So my material is not lying is mild steel range or is there some error?

Comment: How is 54 the same as 57? Is Google known for accurate testing of steel? What other sources are there? Also, is there a possibility your material has been heat treated?

Comment: 55 and 57 are almost same. The question is ultimate tensile strength is constant or it varies if I change material thickness.

Comment: So if 57 is the same as 54 then there is no difference between 1.4 and 2 as that is a fraction of a millimetre ie very small.

Comment: The question remains the same, is ultimate tensile strength is constant for a material?

Comment: Yes, no, maybe - depends on the batch / production quality and the tolerances will depend on the final use.

Answer (score 2):

Mild steel is not a material definition ; It is a general description for the layman so he knows it is not cast iron, copper, aluminum , stainless steel , tool steel ,  etc. ASTM  specifications are a good source for ordering or defining a particular steel. The trivial differences in your tests could easily be normal variations in one heat, certainly with different gages ( thickness).

Answer (score 1):

Constant for **a single** material, subject to variation for a number of examples of a material.

Certainly there are conditions that could weaken certain materials over time.